# when is it better to use One Vs All and when to use One Vs One in Statistics and Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, mathematical-statistics, multi-class, artificial-intelligence

I would love to further understand the uses and the application because while I understand the difference I still don't know which one is better for which type of problem.

Comment: From my experience sometimes you don't have a choice as you only have a certain number of training examples in each class. So the dimensionality of your data makes one an obvious choice to optimise the training data you have. Not sure about the other benefits/disadvantages though.

Comment: Fair enough, Thanks